# Is there any alternative for asset and URL in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to link my css file via asset like:

```
@if(session()->has('locale'))
    <?php $file_name = "css/".session()->get('locale').'.css'; ?>
    <link href="{{asset('<?php echo $file_name;?>')}}" rel="stylesheet">
@endif
```

the value `$file_name` is **dr** but at source-view is shows like: `<link href="{{asset('css/dr.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">`
 the link address is no correct it must show `<link href="http://localhost:8000/css/dr.css" rel="stylesheet">`
what should I use instead of asset or url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `{{ }}` will already transform this to php syntax. If you look at `storage/framework/views` there will be some "compiled" files of the view.
There is no need to use `<?php echo ... ?>`. Just use:

```
<link href="{{asset($file_name)}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Make sure your **view** filename is something.**blade**.php

Comment: it is *.blade.php* if no need to use `<?php echo ... ?>` what you suggest I Write? I should write`<link href="{{asset('$file_name')}}" rel="stylesheet">`?

Comment: This, without the single quotes, exactly as posted in the answer. You may want to invest some time reading the docs: https://laravel-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blade/

Comment: If I try what I wrote in comment in source-view it is like this` <link href="http://localhost:8000/$file_name" rel="stylesheet">
`

Comment: Remove the quotes. Copy and paste the code I posted.

Comment: this is correct `<link href="{{asset($file_name)}}" rel="stylesheet">` not `<link href="{{asset('$file_name')}}" rel="stylesheet">`